# How to customize text color of the CheckBoxPreference title

Tags: android

How to change the color of Title text in CheckBoxPreference?

Comment: Hey how exactly did you that Suresh? I was trying to change the color of the title of a preference group and i thought it is similar to what you tried. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @rohan, Please see the posted answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As zenob said this can be solved by a custom layout. Preference layout defined in the framework is used in the application:

custom_preferece_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project Licensed under the 
    Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except 
    in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed 
    under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES 
    OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for 
    the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->

<!-- Layout for a Preference in a PreferenceActivity. The Preference is able 
    to place a specific widget for its particular type in the "widget_frame" 
    layout. -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip" android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip" android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee" android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FF0000" />

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title" android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:maxLines="4" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

textColor attribute is defined for title TextView in the above layout. Use this layout with the checkbox preference in preference xml.

mypreference.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="testcheckbox"
    android:title="Checkbox Title"
    android:summary="Checkbox Summary..."
    android:layout="@layout/custom_preference_layout"></CheckBoxPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Checkbox preference title will have the color defined in the custom layout.

Comment: This is the best answer that I found to customize the CheckBoxPreference widget ... This in combination with using an custom layout containing a simple list will get you to fully customize the PreferenceActivity for your application.

Comment: I cannot find answer for my question, maybe here you will be able to help me. How can I customize checkbox appearance in preferenceScreen? Let's say color of checkbox background? I can add a checkbox in widget_frame, but then, if I've got summaryOn/summaryOff in checkBoxPreference it does not work. For more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004961/custom-checkbox-in-checkboxpreference-summaryon-summaryof Thanks a lot for interest!

Answer (score 6):

One easy solution that i found is to add this to your style

```
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
```

`textColorPrimary` will change the color of title of `checkBoxPreference` and `textColorSecondary` will change the color of `summary`.

Answer (score 2):

You open file color.xml and change to Light Blue #4096ff:

```
<color name="colorAccent">#4096ff</color>
```

Here is the link of Screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txalm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't access CheckBoxPreference layout - it's declared in internal package.

You can still create your own preference with a custom layout.

Comment: Ok, copied the preference.xml from core resources and modifying color of TextView (android:id/title) and setting this as widget layout of CheckBoxPreference has worked.