# Android CheckBoxPreference title color

Tags: android, checkbox, textcolor, preferencescreen

I am using the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6042324/1129612).

But instead of setting the *android:textColor* for the Text View i use

> style="?background_text_color_theme"

which has to set the text color depending on the theme of the application ( white text color for black theme and vice versa). This works in all other places except for CheckBoxPreference.

Changes I made to the link I gave:

```
      <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee" android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        style="?background_text_color_theme" />
```

Here is my style.xml:

```
    <style name="background_text_color_theme_bl">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>

</style>    

     <style name="background_text_color_theme_wh">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>

</style>
```

Themes.Xml:

```
    <style name="Theme.White"  parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="background_text_color_theme">@style/background_text_color_theme_wh</item>
</style> 

   <style name="Theme.Black"  parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="background_text_color_theme">@style/background_text_color_theme_bl</item>
</style>
```

But the text color does not seem to be set according to the style. Can anyone tell me why is it happening?

Thank You.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I did it..Just in case some one needs it in the future.

```
    public class CheckBoxPreferenceClass extends CheckBoxPreference {


    public CheckBoxPreferenceClass(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckBoxPreferenceClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public CheckBoxPreferenceClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

}
```

And in the preference xml use this for the checkbox preference:

```
  <packagename.CheckBoxPreferenceClass
        android:key="@string/imp"
        android:title="@string/title"/>
```