# Setting app stopped when custom CheckBoxPreference

Tags: preferences

I used the answer of this question: [Android CheckBoxPreference title color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004326/android-checkboxpreference-title-color)
But when i deployed to my application, i click to "account setting" section => Settings stoped
.What is wrong here?

Comment: If you give an example of your code and what happens, I suspect that you might get a helpful answer.  As it is, one would need to look at the linked question.  But I would guess that what you are doing might be a bit different.

Comment: I have posted it below. Thank Joel!!

Answer (score 0):

This is my Custom CheckBoxPreference

```js
package vn.com.myapp.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by anubis on 5/16/15.
 */


public class MyCheckBoxPreferences extends CheckBoxPreference {


    public MyCheckBoxPreferences(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyCheckBoxPreferences(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyCheckBoxPreferences(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

And using it

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Options" />

    <vn.com.myapp.view.MyCheckBoxPreferences
        android:checked="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:key="contactSync"
        android:summary="Sum1"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/textColorSecondary"
        android:title="tit1" />

    <vn.com.myapp.view.MyCheckBoxPreferences
        android:editable="false"
        android:checked="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:key="smsSync"
        android:summary="Sum2"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/textColorSecondary"
        android:title="tit2" />
    <vn.com.myapp.view.MyCheckBoxPreferences
        android:checked="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:key="callLogSync"
        android:summary="Sum3"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/textColorSecondary"
        android:title="tit3" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```