# Align CheckBoxPreference To Right Android

Tags: android, checkbox, alignment, preference, checkboxpreference

I want To align the title of check box to right and the box to left because i want to used in Arabic app , How I can Do that ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="testcheckbox"
    android:title="Checkbox Title"
    android:summary="Checkbox Summary..."/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332340/how-to-right-align-preferencesactivity-in-android) question here, duplicate question

Comment: i`m trying to use this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469514/how-to-customize-text-color-of-the-checkboxpreference-title but i cant align the box  only i can align the title and summary !