# How to update the color of checkbox in checkboxpreference programmatically?

Tags: android

As of now checkbox is filled with the toolbar theme color but I need to show checkbox with different color other than toolbar so I need to update checkbox color programmatically in android. How to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

For Checkboxpreference you should use this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6042324/11549280

and

for CheckBox you should use:
Suppose your checkbox is:

```
Checkbox checkbox;
```

To create a ColorStateList programmatically,
Use

```
ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.your_color);
```

and then

```
CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(checkbox, colorStateList);
```

Comment: hi,it is CheckBoxPreference not checbox CheckBoxPreference itself will give you check box in build which cannot be accessed.Plz check

Answer (score 0):

Create theme to your setting activity, add this parameters to the style:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.SettingActivity"  parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar"> 
         <!--when the check box is checked --!>       
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/your-color</item> 
        <!--when the check box is unchecked --!>       
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your-color</item>
  </style>`
```

if you are using AppCompatCheckBox follow the instruction below

Use buttonTint to change color of button and color selector for above 21+ api version.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:buttonTint="@color/checkbox_filter_tint"
                tools:targetApi="21"/>
```

res/colors/checkbox_filter_tint.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/light_gray_checkbox"
          android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/common_red"
          android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: i have my checkbox preference as below:<CheckBoxPreference
        android:title="@string/checkbox_save_notification_title"
        android:key="@string/checkbox_save_notification_key"
        android:summary="@string/checkbox_save_notification_summery"
        android:defaultValue="@bool/checkbox_save_notification_default" />

Comment: i m not using AppCompatCheckBox its CheckBoxPreference